# Why does the thank you page not appear

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this code and after success the thank you page has to appear.
The code executes but remains on the same page and does not redirect to the thank you page.

```
   <a id="ajaxpost" class="large red button round" href="javascript:void(0)">לחץ כאן<a>

<script>

$("#ajaxpost").click(function () {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: $('#newsletter').serialize(),
       url: 'http://www.stress-free-life.co.il/lists/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1',
        success: function (msg) {
           openWin();

           $('#Name').val('');
           $('#email').val('');
        window.location = "www.bkalut.co.il/thankyou.html";
       },
       failure: function (msg) {
           alert('Sorry, we were unable to process your subscription.');
       }
   });
```

});

Comment: what error you getting in the console?

Comment: can you debug if there is any error in script

Comment: please also consider fixing your question...

Comment: there is a console error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.stress-free-life.co.il/lists/?p=subscribe&id=1. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.stress-free-life.co.il' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://www.bkalut.co.il' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: So the problem has nothing to do with the redirect, the problem has to do with the fact you are making a cross domain call. If you do not control that other domain, you are not going to be able to make an Ajax call to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = "http://www.bkalut.co.il/thankyou.html";
```

Add http:// before your url

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a cross site issue, this is worth a try.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFP94/)

Code Snippet:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "<your url>",
      async:false
    }).done(function() { 
       window.location.href="www.google.com";
    });
```

Do remember to have async as false

Comment: still the same problem it not solve the problem i'm still in the same page

Comment: what is openWin()? I am sure you getting a console error so can you look up in your console and let us know the error?

Comment: Whoever has downvoted can that person give me the reason for the same?

Comment: that's what the console error is:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.stress-free-life.co.il/lists/?p=subscribe&id=1. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.stress-free-life.co.il' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://www.bkalut.co.il' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: `window.location` and `window.location.href` is the same thing in the end. It will not make a difference.

Comment: @mattanlevy: I have updated my answer let me know if it worked for you or not

Comment: @mattanlevy: any luck on this one?